# Node able to access nodePort

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have just started understanding Kubernetes and met with this specific problem.
I followed these official steps https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/#what-youll-need
*I have a window 11 amdx64 machine. used .exe file*

and by the time I reached `minikube service hello-minikube`

browser on visiting http://192.168.49.2:30051/ say's
This site can’t be reached.

with `kubectl port-forward service/hello-minikube 7080:8080` works fine and I can access the below on visiting http://localhost:7080/

```
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=127.0.0.1
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://localhost:8080/

SERVER VALUES:
server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001

HEADERS RECEIVED:
accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br
accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.9,ml;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7
connection=keep-alive
host=localhost:7080
sec-ch-ua=" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
sec-ch-ua-mobile=?0
sec-ch-ua-platform="Windows"
sec-fetch-dest=document
sec-fetch-mode=navigate
sec-fetch-site=cross-site
sec-fetch-user=?1
upgrade-insecure-requests=1
user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36
BODY:
-no body in request-
```

I am not sure why I can't access the container with nodePort. I want to know if it's a .yaml configuration issue or a network firewall issue. ill be going over ingress and load balancers but before I'd really like to know what's the deal with nodePort

K'8 Components Details

pods

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
hello-minikube-7bc9d7884c-48959   1/1     Running   0          153m   172.17.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

deployments

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl get deployments -o wide
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE    CONTAINERS   IMAGES                      SELECTOR
hello-minikube   1/1     1            1           154m   echoserver   k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4   app=hello-minikube
```

services

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl get services -o wide
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE    SELECTOR
hello-minikube   NodePort    10.109.39.95   <none>        8080:30051/TCP   154m   app=hello-minikube
kubernetes       ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          156m   <none>
```

Endpoints

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl get endpoints -o wide
NAME             ENDPOINTS           AGE
hello-minikube   172.17.0.5:8080     3h56m
kubernetes       192.168.49.2:8443   3h58m
```

`kubectl get deploy hello-minikube -o yaml`

```
C:\Users\user>kubectl get deploy hello-minikube -o yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-15T13:26:15Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: hello-minikube
  name: hello-minikube
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "638"
  uid: 4cc2a69a-8d0a-4c38-af27-75747546afe4
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-minikube
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: hello-minikube
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: echoserver
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-05-15T13:26:25Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-05-15T13:26:25Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-05-15T13:26:15Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-05-15T13:26:25Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "hello-minikube-7bc9d7884c" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the deployed deployment and the service (`kubectl get deploy hello-minikube -o yaml`)?

Comment: added to the question